# Asterisk / Digium card / FreePBX : how to define on which inbound port I want to connect the telephony line on my 4-ports telephony card?

Tags: asterisk, telephony, pbx

I am a newbie with Asterisk.

I have a 4-ports Digium telephony card. I connected my analogic telephony line to one of these 4 ports.

I have set up an IVR thanks to the FreePBX interface.

I have set an inboud route (to my IVR) in the connectivity menu of FreePBX (not sure that I did that properly).

My IVR does not work (nothing happen when I call).

Anyone can help ?

Comment: This is almost certainly the wrong forum for this question.  From memory (I've shifted away from Digium cards a long time ago), each interface on the card has a different ID - I think its zap0-zap3 - You should be able to find out by looking at the system boot logs.  ZAP0 = port1, ZAP2 = port2 etc.   Another thing to do is to log into a console, then see what Asterisk does (asterisk -vvvr) - you may find the zap interfaces are not set to route inbound calls to the correct context.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 port card, each one named as

```
DADHI/1
DAHDI/2
DAHDI/3
DAHDI/4
```

Also you can group any number of ports and use group like

```
DAHDI/g0
```

You can check what exactly you configured by issue

```
dahdi_cfg -vvv
```

You can see what is gooing on on your asterisk server via console

```
asterisk -r
```

For more info about configuration see

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/chan_dahdi.conf

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/DAHDI